# Just started learning python and am so lost on getting installed package to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, module, install.packages

First some preemptive info:
-py version 3.12.2
-pip 24.0

I started my python journey learning some coding basics and diving into some online excercises. Using it in a practical way has been very motivating until I got to Exercise 17 here:
https://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/06/06/17-decode-a-web-page.html

This exercise requires some pip installs to build a web scraper. The script imports are 'requests' and 'bs4'. After installing both, I run test script and get a bug at the first import:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

I went into a rabbithole of websleuthing for more information and can't figure out where I went wrong. On initial install, I got a warning message stating that the installation was not done to 'PATH'. Again, I'm very new to this so I may have setup something incorrectly. Did this warning have anything to do with why it won't work?

Thank you for your help

Attempted to reinstall packages, all required dependencies are fullfilled.
Verified python version and pip version.

pip show requests:
`Name: requests`
`Version: 2.31.0`
`Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.`
`Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io`
`Author: Kenneth Reitz`
`Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org`
`License: Apache 2.0`
`Location: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages`
`Requires: certifi, charset-normalizer, idna, urllib3`
`Required-by:  PS C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Matt\Documents\Learning & Development\Online Course Material\Programming\Python\PracticePython.org>`

import sys; print(sys.path):
`PS C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Matt\Documents\Learning & Development\Online Course Material\Programming\Python\PracticePython.org>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\me\OneDrive\Matt\Documents\Learning & Development\Online Course Material\Programming\Python\PracticePython.org'; & 'c:\Users\me\OneDrive\Matt\Documents\Learning & Development\Online Course Material\Programming\Python\PracticePython.org\tutorial_env\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '59771' '--' 'C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Matt\Documents\Learning & Development\Online Course Material\Programming\Python\PracticePython.org\Exercise-17 Decode A Webpage.py'`

Comment: Show us the exact command you used to install those modules.

Comment: I've used: `pip install requests` `pip3 install requests` and `py -m pip install --upgrade requests`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please ensure you're installing the modules into the same environment that you're running the python command in.  Which Python binary are you using and what is the path of the installed modules?

Comment: Now show us the output of this command `pip show requests`, and the output of this short code sample `import sys; print(sys.path)`.  And please put those items in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: You have two separate installations of python on your computer.  One is in `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0`, and one is in `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312`.

Comment: pip is using the first installation, and you're running code using python in the second installation.

Comment: Did you intentionally install two different pythons?

Comment: No sir, so I should attempt to uninstall and start over?

Comment: looking in my installed programs, I see Python 3.12, Python 3.12.1 (64-bit), and Python Launcher

Comment: If you didn't intend to have two different installations, then you might want to remove one of them, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll try this. I think I got a bit too quick with the setup. I found some information on swapping system environment variables that might be a fix aside from uninstalling. From system settings: Edit the System Environment Variables > Environment Variables > PATH > *Move preferred version to the top of the list* To allow the terminals to swap between multiple venv's.

Comment: Solved, thank you John for your help. The problem was I had the Microsoft Store Version. Manipulation of sys env variables did nothing. I just uninstalled everything and reinstalled correctly (to path). Got a working web scraper now.